# Force formatting text encoded by user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I used a ViewModel class as described below:

```
public class ProductCreateModel
{
    [DisplayName("Id product:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the id.")]
    public string IdProduct { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Description:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the description.")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

How can I proceed to force users to encode an id product in format 11.111 so 2 numbers followed by dot followed by 3 numbers.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Regex validator:

```
[DisplayName("Id product:")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the id.")]
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3}$")]
public string IdProduct { get; set; }
```

Comment: That's my fault! It worked, sorry. I mistyped something. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression validation attribute like this:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d{2}\.\d{3}?$")
```